# Which db managment software can copy from one sqlite3 table to another for fields which are common in both?

Tags: database

We are looking for db management software which can copy from one sqlite3 table to another for fields which are common to both tables. For example, if table A has column name and address. Table B has name , address and contact. The db management software can copy column name and address from table A to table B or vise verse.

The db management software we found can only copy when 2 tables have exactly the same structure (field name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL Data Examiner](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql_data_examiner/)

Comment: Unfortunately the tool does not support sqlite3, and postgres.

Comment: I think it could access "other sources". Haven't tried it myself but ODBC & OLEDB might be an option.